# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta eloquent con filtros?

Tags: php, html, laravel, artisan

Estoy tratando de hacer un listado de usuario por rol, donde tengo 3 roles cliente, secretaria y recepcionista, quisiera poder obtener cierto registro con esas condiciones. Estuve probando con when en laravel, pero veo no lo estoy planteando bien. Como podria hacer bien el filtro para obtener ciertos registro por el rol de la sesion.

Codigo de mi controller

$role = auth()->user()->role;

```
    $users = User::query()
                ->when($role, fn($query, $role) 
                => $query->where('role', $role))        
                ->when($role, fn($query, $role) 
                => $query->where('role', $role))     
                ->when($role, fn($query, $role) 
                => $query->where('role', $role))                 
                ->get();
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.
Gracias

Comment: En principio, estás repitiendo lo mismo 3 veces, con hacerlo 1 vez bastaría. Luego, no se entiende qué es lo que no te funciona

Comment: Estas usando laravel-permissions de spatie ?